# MongoDB aggregation with 'and' and 'or' and 'in' conditions

Tags: mongodb, match, pipeline, lookup, aggregation

```
{ "$match": { "$and": [ { "is_active": { "$eq": True }},{ "is_delete": { "$eq": False }}] } }
```

This is my match condition for lookup aggregation and it is working fine.

Now I need to add two more conditions and these are not mandatory fields they may be **null or not**, I think I need `or` condition inside, with `and` condition as top query when I pass `abc` and `xyz`, it is working, if I didn't pass both or anyone its failing (not returning proper data).

```
{ "abc_id" : { "$eq": abc } },{ "xyz_id" : {"$in": [xyz]} }
```

How can I achieve this? Thanks for inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can includ `or` :

```
{
  "$match": {
    "$and": [
      { "is_active": { "$eq": True } },
      { "is_delete": { "$eq": False } },
      {
        "$or": [
          { "abc_id": { "$eq": abc } },
          { "xyz_id": { "$in": [xyz] } }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: its working but it needs any one data like abc or xyz for the above code snippet, i used if condition for with filter and without and its worked with single data also means either abc or xyz.